# One unique record from same table

Tags: sql, unique

I have a table that contains the following...

### ID Type

```
1  Final
1  Primary
2  Final
3  Primary
3  Final
4  Primary
```

I really want to only capture `Type = Final` but if the ID does not correspond to `Type = Final` then I need to capture `Type = Primary`. I only want one row per ID.

My result should look like this:

### ID TYPE

```
1 Final
2 Final
3 Final
4 Primary
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are talking about SQL, and that `Final` and `Primary` are the *only* possible values, and there are no `null` values, then:

```
select id,min(type)
from my_table
group by id
```